# PHP Regex String in Array

Tags: php, regex, arrays, post

I would like to be able to set a global username like `<anythinghere>@domain3.com` as a username value in the $usernames array (in code below). This is so that I can then go and redirect users based on domain, having already been "authenticated".

I will put example in code below.

Can i do something like `$usernames = array("username@domain1.com", $X)` where `$X = <anything-so-long-as-not-blank>@domain3.com`?

Full Code Below:

```
<?php

//VALIDATE USERS
$usernames = array("username@domain1.com", "username2@domain1.com", "username3@domain1.com", "username1@domain2.com", "username2@domain2.com", "username1@domain3.com");
$passwords = array("password1", "password2", "password3", "password4", "password5", "password6");


//REDIRECT SPECIFIC VALID USERS OR DOMAIN
function get_page($username) {
$username = strtolower($username);
switch ($username) {
    case "username@domain1.com"    : return "http://www.google.com";
    case "username2@domain1.com"    : return "http://www.yahoo.com";
    case "username3@domain1.com"    : return "http://www.stackoverflow.com";
    case "username1@domain2.com"    : return "http://www.serverfault.com";
        }
return preg_match('/@domain3\.com$/',$username) ?
"http://www.backblaze.com" : "DefaultBackupPage.php";
}
$page = get_page($_POST['username']);

for($i=0;$i<count($usernames);$i++)

{
  $logindata[$usernames[$i]]=$passwords[$i];
}

$found = 0; 

for($i=0;$i<count($usernames);$i++) 
{ 
   if ($usernames[$i] == $_POST["username"]) 
   { 
   $found = 1; 
   } 
} 
if ($found == 0) 
{ 
   header('Location: login.php?login_error=1'); 
   exit; 
} 
if($logindata[$_POST["username"]]==$_POST["password"])
{
   session_start();
   $_SESSION["username"]=$_POST["username"];
   header('Location: '.$page);
   exit;
}
else
{
   header('Location: login.php?login_error=1');
   exit;
}
?>
```

@inhan Has already helped me like a champ. I am wondering if any one can get me over the line? Cheers!

Comment: There seems to be something odd with your logic. You want to supply a username with wildcards, fair enough - but what do you want to match it against?

Comment: So I want a username that can have ANY text before @domain.com to MATCH to. The section that redirects usernames then can redirect a valid username. Not send the address to the error page. So basically I am validating a domain. But it has to be a value in that $username array or I have to rewrite everything! (Which I'm not allowed to do)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code needed a clean-up first. There's a bunch of errors in it if you do a test run. It's also a bit hard to read IMO.

I've attached a working code sample below.

```
// Get users
$input_pwd = ( isset( $_POST["password"] ) ? $_POST["password"] : '' );
$input_user = ( isset( $_POST["username"] ) ? $_POST["username"] : '' );

// Your pseudo database here ;)
$usernames = array(
    "username@domain1.com",
    "username2@domain1.com",
    "username3@domain1.com",
    "username1@domain2.com", 
    "/[a-z][A-Z][0-9]@domain2\.com/",   // use an emtpy password string for each of these
    "/[^@]+@domain3\.com/"              // entries if they don't need to authenticate
);

$passwords = array( "password1", "password2", "password3", "password4", "", "" );

// Create an array of username literals or patterns and corresponding redirection targets
$targets = array(
    "username@domain1.com"           => "http://www.google.com",
    "username2@domain1.com"          => "http://www.yahoo.com",
    "username3@domain1.com"          => "http://www.stackoverflow.com",
    "username1@domain2.com"          => "http://www.serverfault.com",
    "/[a-z][A-Z][0-9]@domain2\.com/" => "http://target-for-aA1-usertypes.com",
    "/[^@]+@domain3\.com/"           => "http://target-for-all-domain3-users.com",
    "/.+/"                           => "http://default-target-if-all-else-fails.com",
);

$logindata = array_combine( $usernames, $passwords );

if ( get_user_data( $input_user, $logindata ) === $input_pwd ) {

   session_start();
   $_SESSION["username"] = $input_user;
   header('Location: ' . get_user_data( $input_user, $targets ) );
   exit;

} else {
    // Supplied username is invalid, or the corresponding password doesn't match
   header('Location: login.php?login_error=1'); 
   exit; 
}

function get_user_data ( $user, array $data ) {

    $retrieved = null;

    foreach ( $data as $user_pattern => $value ) {

        if (
               ( $user_pattern[0] == '/' and preg_match( $user_pattern, $user ) )
            or ( $user_pattern[0] != '/' and $user_pattern === $user)
        ) {

            $retrieved = $value;
            break;

        }

    }

    return $retrieved;

}
```

Comment: Thanks Michael, that is definitely much better laid out code. My problem is that even with this setup I am unable to type in any prefix before @domain.com and be redirected. Because I am still not a valid user. We have not defined the ability to validate any prefix at domain.com. Redirect, yes, but because not a valid user, we get thrown to an error page. At least that is as I have read it? Please correct me if I am wrong! Cheers.

Comment: Yes, the code above redirects valid users to the target defined in the array. Invalid logins get sent off to the error page. That's how I read your code and your question ... Anyway, if you want to redirect invalid users as well, why don't you just call get_redirection_target when handling them, instead of sending them to 'login.php?login_error=1'?

Comment: Cheers mate, basically my goal is to make any text included before a valid DOMAIN be accepted ON WHOLE as a valid username. Not to redirect invalid usernames. There are two parts to it, the redirection is spot on, the validating a domain name part is where I am now having trouble. If it cannot be done this way, I will take that on the chin. I just wish you could put some regex in the username array like [a-z][A-Z]@domain.com and have that work... Thank you for your efforts thus far!

Comment: Slowly getting there ;) So you want any username to be legit if it matches the pattern "/whatever pattern you come up with/@domain.com". Right? Do these folks need to supply a password? Do they all have the same password?

Comment: Awesome we are on the same page! Haha. Yes, they all have the same password PER DOMAIN. They do not supply password. Although, I guess you could say they supply the username prefix to the domain.

Comment: Just edited my answer. I didn't change much, really ;) Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much Michael for persisting! You have been a great help!

Comment: Hey Michael, as a follow up is there a way to make the username entries case INsensitive? with "strcasecmp" somewhere? I might make this a separate quesiton.

Comment: Just append the "i" modifier to the regex you want to be case-insensitive, as in "/some regex pattern/i".